# SQL Database Connection is not establishing with java Web Application server which is in DMZ

Tags: java, sql-server-2000

I have a Java web application which deployed at DMZ server. I have written the below code for local machine database connection establishment in web application

```
url= jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://" + ipAddress + ":1433;databaseName=" + loginForm.getDbName();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, loginForm.getDbUserName(), loginForm.getDbPWD());
```

Now I am accessing the application through internet and  passing the ipAddress of local machine, local machine dB, username, password.

but getting the below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can try:

1. Check that your server is listening on that port
2. Check that your server will allow traffic on that port
3. Check that any other intermediary firewall will allow traffic on that port
4. Ping the server
5. See if you can telnet to the server/port
6. See if you can access any other services on the server (web, email, whatever)

The error seems to suggest that the server is contactable, but it is either not listening on the port, or it is refusing to talk to you - have you checked the server logs?

Answer (score 1):

**The web application simply cannot establish a TCP/IP connection with the specified database.**

The machine whose IP address is in the `ipAddress` variable should be accessible (through network) from the web application server.

Can you telnet the 1433 port of `ipAddress` from **the web application machine**?

Check if:

- The database is online at the (default) 1433 port;
- The database is accepting incoming TCP/IP connections ([check this link to learn how to enable it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841252/en-us));
- There are no firewalls between the web application server and the database server.

Also, as you seem to be inputting the `ipAddress` from a form, check for eventual typos and `String` conversions.